# How to show static row in newly created table in SQL Server WITHOUT DDL operation using select

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I created a new table.

We need output:

```
Table: User
columns: id|name|date
values : 0 | 0  |0
```

If the table contains value then not show static data

Note: only use select

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If table is empty we need to show one static row in table without insert command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds as if you are looking for a conditional UNION:

```
select id, name, date
from the_table
union all
select 0, '', null
where not exists (select * from the_table);
```

The second part of the union returns constant values but only if `the_table` contains no rows.